# Laravel:Uploading to server with SSL certificate

Tags: php, laravel, apache

Do i need to config some in codes before uploading to server with https:// because my problem is if we upload into production the pages are always not found. Someone told me that they didn't do anything in their code before uploading to server with https:// and it still working fine. I tried different things to make it work like configuring htaccess, AppServiceProvider and routes but its unfortunate.

.**Htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Force SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://hiflyer.ca/% [R,L]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

**AppServiceProvider**

```
    <?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);

    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
       if (env('APP_ENV') === 'production') {
        $this->app['request']->server->set('HTTPS', true);
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

correct, you need only config httaccess,it auto http->https, when enter http://----> https://, if database save http:// in rows, you need use Mysql replace http:// to https://

```html
RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```